# Could I create dialog in onPrepareDialog() instead of in onCreateDialog()?

Tags: android

I want to refresh dialog's display in `onConfigurationChanged` after locale changed by doing `showDialog(ID)` in `onConfigurationChanged`.

I know it's normal to create a dialog in `onCreateDialog()`, and refresh the title or buttons in `onPrepareDialog()` , but I got so many dialogues need to be refreshed.

Could I just return "null" in `onCreateDialog()`, and do real work in `onPrepareDialog()`?

Thanks for your help.
Amy

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this, especially if anyone else is working with the code, however the real question is did you try it? Sounds like a simple matter of cut & paste.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried, and no dialog is displayed. So no way to skip the refresh for each dialog.

Comment: And I found that is because in Activity.java it will not do dispatchOnCreate() if dialog is null. It seems there is no way could let me do what I want. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Android calls onCreateDialog for once, but onPrepareDialog used to change the dialog's content...